# Sabouraud dextrose agar breaking?

Tags: lab-techniques, mycology, cell-culture, yeast

I recently started growing some Geotrichum Candidum (GC) on Sabouraud dextrose agar (SDA) beds. The SDA was poured into sterilized petri dishes. After setting the plates in a cooler (20 C) for a day, I then inoculated the plates with a tiny smidge of GC. The GC is growing happily in that environment.

However, today on day 3, **I noticed a crack across the SDA** like shown in the picture below.

What does this mean? Did I prepare the plate wrong? Or is my GC just a bit naughty and somehow burrowing into the SDA?

*Please note I am not a trained biologist, I've learned the skills I require for my activity from online resources and advice.*

[image: a crack in sabouraud]

Comment: It could just be the agar drying out.

Comment: My initial thought. The cooler is at 80 % relative humidity though. Isn't that enough?

Comment: I suppose evaporation can occur at any relative humidity less than 100%. Is the agar shrinking in terms of thickness and/or peeling away from the side of the plate? These are also signs of desiccation.

Comment: I see no signs of desiccation on the surface nor on the edges of the agar.

Comment: After closer inspection it seems to be desiccation. I've added a 1/4 teaspoon demineralized water in the lid (inverted dish).

Comment: @neydroydrec If that turns out to solve your problem, can you please add it as an answer to your own question? Then  it will help the next person with a mysterious crack in their agar.

Comment: Sure. Waiting for results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot be entirely sure about the cause as I have not been able to reproduce this situation subsequently, but based on the comparison of what I did before and do now, it seems the cause was the wrong dosage of agar per water, i.e. an excess of agar.
Hoping this may help others.